# ReactiveCocoa: why rac_textSignal doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Why this doesn't work:

```
[self.phoneTextField.rac_textSignal subscribeNext:^(NSString *text) {
    self.viewModel.textFieldText = text;
}];
```

while this works well, even when clear button clicked:

```
RAC(self.viewModel, textFieldText) = RACObserve(self.phoneTextField, text);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rac_textSignal is only triggered when UIControlEventAllEditingEvents fires and that doesn't happen for clear. Here is a workaround for both cases:

```
[[RACSignal 
  merge:@[self. phoneTextField.rac_textSignal, RACObserve(self.phoneTextField, text)]] 
  subscribeNext:^(NSString* text) {
      // do something here
  }];
```

BR,

Comment: Second option seems to be shorter and it also works, when text changes.

Comment: That is true :)